# How to get id from drop down list java server pages

Tags: jsp, el

My question related to java tag library

I am new in using java server pages expression library  tag but i am facing problem to get id of value .

How to fetch id and value from drop down selection a map in expression language.

Comment: Do u want to list drop down values from MAP using jstl?

Comment: Yes I want to get Id and Value from Map using jstl

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>    
     <c:forEach var="entry" items="${pageScope.map}">
        <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-loop-hashmap-or-hashtable-in-jsp-example.html#ixzz4eUhpDEac